# python twisted simple client - server communication

Tags: python, client, twisted, irc

Trying to get a simple python twisted client - server application working.  The intention will be to use this to control a few IRC bots; like a master console to issue commands to all (5ish) bots.

The attached code will form into the server code, someday.  For the moment, I'm using telnet to simulate the IRC bots (clients) connecting to the "party line".

What I'm stuck on is, how do I, from the server application attached, sendLine to all the bots?  Every time I create a loop to get raw_input, I end up stalling the execution.  I've thought about testing against a connection state function, but can't seem to find that (if connection is true, raw_input sort of logic).

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor

class bottalk(LineReceiver):

    botlist = []

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        botlistspot = len(self.botlist)
        self.botlist.append(line)
        print self.botlist[botlistspot] + " checked in."

class botfactory(Factory):

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return bottalk()

reactor.listenTCP(8123, botfactory())
reactor.run()
```

I've tried to place the following raw_input inside of the LineReceiver class, outside.  All over..  I want this raw_input prompt to continually prompt for input, not just after a event like a line received - all the time..  I want the server bot console always ready to accept my input and sendLine to all the bots.

```
sendLine(raw_input("> "))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `raw_input` at all. Instead, instantiate a `stdio.StandardIO`, giving its constructor an instance of your `LineReceiver` subclass. The `lineReceived` you defined in the subclass will be called whenever a new line is available on `stdin`, and then you can broadcast it to the bots.

[This example from the Twisted site](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/stdiodemo.py) demonstrates the idea.

Comment: Would you explain a bit more?  I'm very new to Python and OOP - maybe a quick example?  I don't want the answer flat out, just a demonstration if it's not too much work.  Thanks!  :)

Comment: There's an example linked in the answer.  Can you describe what more you'd like an example of?

Comment: The question states that your problem is that `raw_input` blocks the execution of your Twisted application. Please do take a look at [the link with the example provided in the answer](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/stdiodemo.py). It's a straight and simple demonstration of how to do non-blocking equivalent of `raw_input` in Twisted. If your question is about something else, feel free to edit it and clarify!

Comment: I'm just a bit lost on how to connect a LineReceiver to an instance of stdio.StandardIO.

Comment: @user1675884 Have you looked at the example? Instantiate `twisted.internet.stdio.StandardIO` with the `LineReceiver` instance as the sole argument to the constructor. It's in line 77 of the example.